# Distance from an object.. Where is the camera origine?

Tags: opencv, c++, distance-metrics

I compute the distance from an object (Chessboard) using OpenCv and my camera parameters using those steps:

findChessboardCorners

solvePnP

->Distance

The distance I get is between two points: the chessboard and the camera. My question is where is the origine of my camera?

I know perfectly about my Chessboard but not my camera in terms of reference.

Comment: Have you calibrated your camera? and what the reference point for calibration?

Comment: @MimSaad Yes I calibrated my camera and the reference point is the corner of the chessboard

Comment: Ok, so you have distance of checkerboard from the camera?

Comment: @MimSaad Yes exactly

Comment: if by distance you euclidean distance, then infinite number of x,y and z's can be the solution. Or you mean depth (ie only Z)?

Comment: @MimSaad By distance I mean the euclidean distance from the translation vector sqrt(x²+y²+z²)

Comment: So you see, infinite number of solutions exists for sqrt(x²+y²+z²)=Distance ! Unless you introduce some constrains.

Comment: @MimSaad This is not my question, I'll check that later. Now I want to know where is the origine of the camera